# Asp.net c# button clicked event does not add new string to arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating shopping cart and I am having problems to add new string to arraylist. It only adds once. I have tried declare arraylist in load page method and also tried to assign to session variable, as in code bellow.
Result: I get only one string in arraylist even button been pressed manytimes.

```
ArrayList test;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test = new ArrayList();
            Session["array"] = test;
        }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ArrayList test = (ArrayList)Session["array"];

                test.Add("a");
                label1.Text = test.Count +"";
                Session["array"] = test;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is because in every postback your `Page_Load` method is called, so `test` is always set as `new ArrayList();`

try this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            test = new ArrayList();
            Session["array"] = test;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked, thanks. I have not used this before because I am using updated panel and I thought it doesn't do postback. But all works now.

Comment: That's great, just remember that the UpdatePanel remove the requirement to refresh the whole page with each postback, which improves the user experience, because only request the item required